# Insert word "booked" into the selected pair in time using json_encode using Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have this check in time and check out time in a booking system. Upon confirmation I want the selected time to add a word "booked" beside time. For example 10:00 to 14:00 it will show as booked.

```
00:00
01:00
02:00
03:00
04:00
05:00
06:00
07:00
08:00
09:00
10:00 booked
11:00 booked
12:00 booked
13:00 booked
14:00 booked
15:00
16:00
17:00
18:00
19:00
20:00
21:00
22:00
23:00
```

I have already got the above in my script, upon saving into the database using json_encode this is the output

```
["00:00","1:00","2:00","3:00","4:00","5:00","6:00","7:00","8:00","9:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"]
```

The booked word is not in there in the

```
"10:00-Booked","11:00 -Booked","12:00-booked","13:00-booked","14:00-booked"
```

Here is my script below

```
  $checkTime = $confirmAdmin['checkin_time'];

    $checkOut = $confirmAdmin['checkout_time'];

  $checkTimeExp = explode(":", $checkTime);

$checkOutExp = explode(":", $checkOut);

$tues = json_decode($room['day_tuesday']);

$tArray = array();
            foreach($tues as $key=>$tue){
                echo "<br>";
                $n = $checkOutExp[0];
                $items = range($checkTimeExp[0], $n);
                $sum = array_sum($items);
                foreach($items as $key=>$item){
                    $tt = $item;

                    if($tt == $tue){
                        $booked = "booked";
                        echo $booked; 
                    }
                }       

                echo $tArray[] = $tue;
            }


 echo json_encode($tArray);
```

The output of my `json_encode` is that there is no word Booked.

Comment: Have you tried to `implode` the booked value into the existing record?

Comment: no i didnt add implode

Comment: can you add an implode script?